# Android Webview redirecting after x seconds

Tags: android, android-webview, android-timer

So i'm trying to redirect from a webview to another activity after X seconds. The problem is that the new activity is launched two times for some reason..

any solutions? Sample code below.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

            final Timer timer =  new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, RegistrerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }, 5000);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

              //Code for response 

            }
```

Comment: Why you are writing redirection code in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**

Comment: put your code inside `onPageStarted` or `onPageFinished` instead of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Comment: I don't know @HarishKamboj. Saw another post where they did it.

Comment: @Toby Do you know what exactly **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** do?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit omg.. that was it. Workes fine now. Thx!

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: @HarishKamboj i'm guessing it is called before the url is loaded? or

Comment: Yes, it is. It will even call again if the website has redirections. But good to hear that your problem has been solved.